# Checking a number represented as a string in C

Tags: c

I would like to check if a number is larger than 0.

The 0 is in string format

How do I either

1. Compare the value to a string representation of 0
2. Cast the string to an int

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: use [atoi()](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/atoi.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atoi()` will convert string into integer.

Comment: You really shouldn't use atoi() anymore - it can't detect errors and you can't specify a number base

Answer (score 5):

[strtol()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers offer you a way to convert the number to an integral datatype to perform your comparison, which is a better general solution (and what I would use first), but in this case we can cheat:

1. Skip through leading whitespace in the string.
2. If the first character is a `'-'`, it's a negative number, and it's less than zero. Return false. If the character is a `'+'`, skip it.
3. Skip any leading `'0'` characters.
4. If the next character is a digit that is not `'0'`, you've got a positive number, which is greater than zero. Return true.
5. If the next character is a `'.'`, skip it and repeat steps 3-4.
6. If you get here, then all the digits were zero. Zero isn't greater than zero, so return false.

Of course, if you need (or expect) to do more than compare the string to a value, go ahead and convert it with your favorite variation of `strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the `strtoul()` or `atoi()` functions in libc to convert a string to an integer.

Comment: I wouldn't convert it to an unsigned (`strtoul()`) to test if something is greater than zero. ;)

Answer (score 0):

if it is hw, your teacher most likely wants to go char by char, so take the ascii value and subtract '0' from it.

If it is longer then a single digit, go char by char, taking the result and multiplying it by 10^i, and adding it to the total

*i is the ith char